# Need help understanding an example in Dummit & Foote: Example 12.3.(5) on page 499

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

[image]

Please see a screen shot above for the example in the book.

I don't quite understand why there are 56 similarity classes eventually. For a $3\times3$ matrix with complex entries, if the diagonal entries in its Jordan form are from the 6th roots of unity (and the three entries are distinct as described in the example), then we should choose 3 out of 6, which simply is 20 different similarity classes. Can anyone explain in more detail why Dummit & Foote find 56 classes? Anything would be appreciated!

Comment: I think your difficulty is in the statement that $m_A(x)$ has no repeated roots.  That doesn't mean the diagonalized $A$ has no repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: @BenW - Yes, that's exactly why I got stuck. Everything is clear to me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the same root more than once, of course, and if you don't have a primitive sixth root you need both a square root (ie $-1$) and a cube root. Don't forget that $1$ is also a sixth root of unity.

Let $a$ be a primitive $6^{th}$ root of unity.

Suppose $a$ appears: there is one class $(a, a, a)$, five classes $(a, a, b)$ with $b \neq a$ and $15$ classes $(a, b, c)$ where $b$ and $c$ are different from $a$ but may be equal. That makes $21$, which is already more than your $20$.

It is not easy to count, and I made a silly error first time through.

I will leave you to list the others.

Comment: Thanks @Mark for your answer. I found where I messed up, and I got the number 56 figured out, which isn't too bad. Basically if $a$ is a 6th root of unity, we have 6 for the type $(a,a,a)$, 30 classes for $(a,a,b)$ where $a\ne b$, and 20 classes for $(a,b,c)$ where $a,b,c$ are all distinct.